# Создать папку на яндекс диск

Tags: php, curl, yandex-disk

Вот так загружаю файл на яндекс диск.

```
system ("curl --user $yadisk_email:$yadisk_pass -T $file 
https://webdav.yandex.ru/$yadisc_dir");
```

Можно ли также просто создать папку на яндекс диск?
Если нет, то какой самый простой способ подскажите?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй вот так

```
system ("curl -X MKCOL --user $yadisk_email:$yadisk_pass https://webdav.yandex.ru/$new_dir");
```

Подробнее [здесь](https://tech.yandex.ru/disk/doc/dg/reference/mkcol-docpage/).

Comment: Огромное спасибо вам! Все работает на отлично. Вы мой спаситель.